# Creating parent and child simultaneously through nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to make a form that creates a :performer, and associates a multimedia :embed url to a performer. I want a performer to potentially have many embed urls associated with them, so embeds are stored on their own table. When I submit the form to create a new performer, I get two errors regardless of whether or not I leave the url field blank on the form:

```
Embeds performer must exist
Embeds url can't be blank
```

After looking at some similar problems, I find that none of the solutions worked for me. Here is some of the relevant code:

**performers_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @performer = Performer.new
    @performer.embeds.build
end

def create
@performer = Performer.new(performer_params)
    if @performer.save
        flash[:success] = "Performer listed!"
        redirect_to(:back)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Performer was not listed."
        render 'new'
    end
end

def performer_params
    params.require(:performer).permit(:name, :email, :bio, embeds_attributes: [:embed_id, :url, :performer_id, :_destroy])
end
```

**Performer.rb**

```
class Performer < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :name, :bio, :email, :embeds_attributes
has_many :concerts
has_many :embeds, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :performer
accepts_nested_attributes_for :embeds, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

end
```

**Embed.rb**

```
class Embed < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :url, :performer_id
belongs_to :performer, inverse_of: :embeds

validates :url, presence: :true
end
```

**Form**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create Performer') %>
<h1>Create Performer</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@performer) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :bio %>
  <%= f.text_area :bio, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :embeds do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>

      <%= builder.label :url %>
      <%= builder.text_area :url, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= builder.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= link_to "remove", '#' , class: 'remove_fields' %>

  </fieldset>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create performer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious issue except that you probably want a checkbox for `_destroy`. It may help if you can share an extract from the server log showing the params and try dumping the output of `performer_params`

Comment: performer_params output is the following:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mRyDxhMIy/sv7cWft8TI98nVY3XoVg5r+G9gdvzlsWRIhqCL9QRceEHJwuuZSOhyjb7q92rgLfUI3S2Y2LsJ/g==", "performer"=>{"name"=>"faa", "bio"=>"aaa", "email"=>"example@example.ca", "embeds_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"url"=>"da", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Performer"}